# Синхронизация с сервером в NetBeans (с применением git)

Tags: git, netbeans, развертывание

*Разрабатываю проект в IDE NetBeans и попробовал применить в работе git, в результате зашел в тупик. Опишу последовательность своих действий:*

1. Я развернул CMS на удаленном сервере
2. Создал проект получив файлы с удаленного сервера в среде NetBeans. NetBeans сделал их локальный кэш (при сохранении - файлы выгружаются на удаленный сервер)
3. Инициализировал репозиторий git в NetBeans - он создал папку .git в моем локальном кэше
4. Некоторое время работал с проектом, но обнаружил, что новые файлы, которые появились на сервере (в результате установки плагинов для CMS) не синхронизируются с локальными файлами и, соответственно, не попадают в репозиторий гита. ВООБЩЕ никакими встроенными средствами IDE не удавалось добавить их в проект.
5. Тогда я решил инициализировать репозиторий git на удаленном сервере и клонировать созданный коммит на локальный компьютер. Но при переключении на клонированную ветвь NetBeans перестал выгружать изменения на сервер. Выдавая окно, что проект поврежден. При попытке зайти в свойства проекта - тоже окно "Проект поврежден". В диалоговом окне "Проблемы проекта" - пусто.
6. В браузере репозитория git удалил Удаленные ветви, удалил репозиторий git на сервере - но проблема сохранилась.

Два вопроса:

1. Как мне синхронизировать файлы на удаленном сервере с моим локальным проектом в среде NetBeans?
2. Почему при переключении на клонированную ветку с моего сервера IDE перестает выгружать на сервер файлы и пишет, что проект поврежден?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Answer (score 1):

Ну это причуды самой среды.

Тут либо так либо так.

Сам в подобной ситуевине был.

Вариантов то не много.

Либо работай локально и выгружай в репу на сервере. Но выгружай сразу чтобы оно подхватывалось чтобы ты изменения видел.

Либо работай удаленно по ssh ну а про git, держи его на серваке и на серваке сливай ветки.

Просто делается немного все иначе.

- Разрабатываешь проект (локально/удаленно"тестовый сервер")
- Делаешь коммит на тестовом или локальном.
- Идешь на сервер (боевой). тянешь изменения или отсылаешь их туда с локальной машины/сервера.

Ругаться бинс будет, у него такая вот штука.